# How to get a new column value by calling a custom function

Tags: json, api, parsing, powerbi, powerquery

I am really new with PowerBi. I need to read item id to parsing API then insert to table. In my case, this is what I have in the PowerBI
[image]

I need to get some data from ADO using API, then I create query like this picture below with this script:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://dev.azure.com/XXX/ProjectName/_apis/wit/workitems/3217?api-version=7.0")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source)
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

[image]

My expectation is, I want to query the work item id from `Backlog` table to `Query1`. So in the Query1 I don't need to specify the work item id like this `Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://dev.azure.com/XXX/ProjectName/_apis/wit/workitems/3217?api-version=7.0"))`, It will depend on the work item on `Backlog`, because the work item in the `Backlog` will update automatically on ADO if click refresh on powerbi.

Anyone can help me please, I really appreciate it, I know this is not easy :(